# How to include <?php echo esc_html($product->get_review_count()); ?> in function.php?

Tags: php, echo

I'd like to add :`<?php echo esc_html($product->get_review_count()); ?>` 
in my function which is :

```
function commentaires() {
    print '<p class="commentaires" Id="liste-des_commentaires">Commentaires</p>';
}
```

How can I write that properly ?

To explain, I want to display next to my word "Commentaires", the number of comments.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: http://php.net/string

Answer (score 1):

If number of comments in $product->get_review_count(), than:

```
function commentaires($count) {
    print '<p class="commentaires" Id="liste-des_commentaires">Commentaires '.$count.'</p>';
}
commentaires($product->get_review_count());
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_review_count() on null in /homepages/1/d506077953/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Odecouvertes/wp-content/themes/goodlook/functions.php:44 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/1/d506077953/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Odecouvertes/wp-settings.php(479): include() #1 /homepages/1/d506077953/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Odecouvertes/wp-config.php(70): require_once('/homepages/1/d5...') #2 /homepages/1/d506077953/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Odecouvertes/wp-load.php(37):

Comment: require_once('/homepages/1/d5...') #3 /homepages/1/d506077953/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Odecouvertes/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/homepages/1/d5...') #4 /homepages/1/d506077953/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Odecouvertes/index.php(17): require('/homepages/1/d5...') #5 {main} thrown in /homepages/1/d506077953/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Odecouvertes/wp-content/themes/goodlook/functions.php on line 44

Comment: Maybe it help if I say that I've got a add_action which goes with my function :

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'commentaires' );

Comment: I've tryied to add ($count) to my add action but no way... something is wrong. I've spent so many hours, looking after a solution... help is needed.

Comment: In rating.php file it is written like : <div class="star-rating__votes">
        <a class="star-rating__votes-link" href="#liste-des-commentaires">
            <?php echo esc_html($product->get_review_count()); ?> <?php esc_html_e('Reviews', 'saleszone'); ?> 
        </a>
    </div>

Comment: No one to help ?